Microsoft graph odata metadata has invalid xml contents and so unable to convert it into Openapispec
we would convert metadata file into openapi spec using an XSL style sheet to work around with out existing code that generates integrations using openapi related libs.
But the graph odata metadata(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata) does not look to have valid xml contents(annotation tag's String attribute has special chars like <,& and " etc..) Because of which, the conversion from metadata to openapi is failing citing invalid xml.
Any inputs as to how to overcome this? using Odata specific librares such as Olingo to read the metdata contents would be the second option in my list.  Please suggest.
Escaping the values of Annotaion tag's String attribute does not seem to be working cause there are dobule quotes in its value in the middle of the text.
Olingo seems to be parsing the contents fine. Not sure if it ignores the 'valid'ity of the xml contents for EDM files or what?

Could you please share more details how do you try to convert xml?

Have you seen the official OpenAPI file for MS Graph API? - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-metadata/blob/master/openapi/v1.0/openapi.yaml

@user2250152, we have used an xsl like this to convert. https://tools.oasis-open.org/version-control/browse/wsvn/odata/trunk/spec/examples/V4-CSDL-to-OpenAPI.xsl?sc=1

@Helen the metadata file will be uploaded by end users and we got to support both  metdata and openapi files.
